# How find list of active users Laravel MySQL?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Trips table with a FK, `user_id (int)` and `date (datetime)`. I'm trying to select the list of users for which they are most recently active.

### Trips

`trip_id (PK)`

`user_id (FK)`

`date`

I tried for a long time but I am stuck with the below query. `GROUP BY` `user_id` don't work as MySQL won't allow it (parameters are non aggregate or something along that line), and `DISTINCT` `user_id` only select that particular value without considering the date.

```
SELECT * FROM trips ORDER BY date DESC;
```

I'm also trying to do this in Laravel, but I was trying to wrap my head around how to approach the query before 'translating' it to the ORM version. If anyone has any good ideas do feel free to suggest them as well, thanks!

Comment: Your query looks fine to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just get trips and order those by date, just do this:

```
Trip::orderBy('date', 'desc')->get();
```

But if you want to active get users that have trips during last month (or another period of time):

```
$activeUsers = User::whereHas('trips', function($q) {
    $q->where('date', '>', Carbon::now->subMonths(1));
})->get();
```

This will work if you've put `date` into the `$dates` array of `Trip` model and have defined the relationship:

```
public function trips()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Trip');
}
```

Comment: You mean like this in the Trip model: `protected $dates =['date', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];`?

Comment: Great! I think I got it to work!! Thanks for the tip, I learnt something new!